# Creating directories for log and cgi files on virtual host

Tags: apache, logging, xampp, virtualhost, directory

I have to create directories for log and cgi files within the each site I'm hosting. When I run XAMPP's Apache server with below provided code of httpd-vhosts.conf file I get message:

```
1:23:14 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
1:23:14 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
1:23:14 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
1:23:14 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
1:23:14 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
1:23:14 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
1:23:14 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

This is what my httpd-vhosts.conf file looks

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/sitea"
    ServerName sitea.com
    ServerAlias www.sitea.com
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/sitea/logs">
    Options Indexes IncludesNOEXEC FollowSymLinks
    allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/sitea/cgi-bin">
    Options Indexes IncludesNOEXEC FollowSymLinks
    allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/sitea/html">
    Options Indexes IncludesNOEXEC FollowSymLinks
    allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "C:/xampp/htdocs/sitea/logs/error_log"
    CustomLog "C:/xampp/htdocs/cms/logs/access_log" combined
    ScriptAlias "/cgi-bin/" "C:/xampp/htdocs/sitea/cgi-bin/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you checked Windows Event Viewer?

Comment: Maybe I should have be more precise:

As you can see from the line 4 - my folder is in C:/xampp/htdocs/sitea

And I have to store 3 directories in it: html, log(containing ErrorLog and CustomLog) and cgi-bin(containing ScriptAlias). I don't know how to set those paths

Comment: Try running> Apache>Bin>httpd.exe for the command prompt and then check the error shown.